# SVN command to read revision of a root

Tags: windows, command-line, svn

I want to use the SVN command line to read the latest revision of a root folder, store it into a variable inside a bat file and echo it out.

I just need to find out that revision and store into a variable for later use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn info` shows information. Try:

```
svn info c:\Path\To\Folder
```

If you have [unix-like tools](https://superuser.com/questions/250/is-cygwin-the-best-unix-environment-for-windows) available, you can pipe to grep

```
svn info c:\Path\To\Folder | grep "Revision:"
```

This might work in windows:

```
svn info c:\Path\To\Folder | find "Revision:"
```